# How can I make my turtle complete its turn before moving?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've been working on a WASD-controlled turtle program for a school project. I have this glitch where, if the W key is struck too soon after a turn key, the turtle will move forwards mid-turn and complete the turn after moving. It's not exactly a big problem, but it's a bug I'd like to get sorted out.

```
    from turtle import *
    Screen()
    move = Turtle()

    def forkey():
        move.forward(50)

    def backey():
        move.back(50)

    def rigkey():
        move.right(45)

    def lefkey():
        move.left(45)

    onkey(forkey, "w")
    onkey(backey, "s")
    onkey(rigkey, "d")
    onkey(lefkey, "a")

    listen()
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember, however, that we're not here to solve your homework for you. Please try to elaborate what you've tried, and just try to think aloud here (as far as possible while still keeping it clear). That way, it's both more encouraging for others to help you, more useful for others, and you learn more of it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your event handler while in the event handler to avoid piling up events:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def forkey():
    screen.onkey(None, "w")
    move.forward(50)
    screen.onkey(forkey, "w")

def backey():
    screen.onkey(None, "s")
    move.back(50)
    screen.onkey(backey, "s")

def rigkey():
    screen.onkey(None, "d")
    move.right(45)
    screen.onkey(rigkey, "d")

def lefkey():
    screen.onkey(None, "a")
    move.left(45)
    screen.onkey(lefkey, "a")

move = Turtle()

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(forkey, "w")
screen.onkey(backey, "s")
screen.onkey(rigkey, "d")
screen.onkey(lefkey, "a")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, the next step might be to disable all event handlers while any event handler is active.  Rather than turn them all off explicitly, you might be able to use a global variable to temporarily disable them.

Comment: your idea with global variable (ie. `busy = True/False`) could be more uuniversal. It has to check it before move in every handler. If it is `False` then set `True`, make move, set `False`.